# regexp_like: IDs with n digits, not n+1

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to filter 5-digit IDs out of a varchar column (containing not only the IDs but also some more text), and i have to avoid to select 6 or more digit IDs containing "by chance" the searched 5 digits, so a simply "like" would not work.
I tried "regexp_like" with `[^0-9]*` ahead and after the searched ID, but it looks as if the 0 to n repetition (`*`) gets confused by the negativ selection of digits (`^`).

```
select *
from
  (     select 1 nr, '12345'   txt from dual
  union select 2 nr, '612345'  txt from dual
  union select 3 nr, 'B12345'  txt from dual
  union select 4 nr, '7612345' txt from dual
  union select 5 nr, '7 12345' txt from dual
  union select 6 nr, 'x12345x' txt from dual
  union select 7 nr, 'x12x45x' txt from dual
  union select 8 nr, ' 12345'  txt from dual
  )
where regexp_like (txt,'[^0-9]*12345[^0-9]*')
order by nr
```

I need to select all occurances of "12345", except for those with leading or trailing other **digits** (eg "612345"). Leading or trailing **characters**, **blanks**, other **signs** or beginning / end of line should by allowed.
So only rows nr 1, 3, 5, 6 and 8 should by selected.

Could you help me please.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If value is `612345 12345`, then this should selected or not ?

Comment: YES, as "612345 12345" contains (in the second part) "12345" without DIRECTLY leading or trailing digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `*` you're searching for 0 or more occurrences, which still matches `612345`, you could do the following:

```
where regexp_like(txt, '(^|[^0-9]+)12345([^0-9]+|$)')
```

(using `+` to ensure you're matching at least one non-digit character `|` or being at the beginning or end)

See also [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4136f/5)

Comment: use \D for non digits '(^|\D+)12345(\D+|$)'

Comment: THANKS A LOT! (It seems that I got confused with 0+ combined with negativ selection ;-)